# Flutter - Using Timer and .cancel() function

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

*** UPDATE ***

I have a problem. When I use a Timer in Flutter and cancel() it afterwards, but as soon the cancel method is triggered, nothing happens.

```
var counter = 0;

Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {

developer.log('Actual counter ' + counter.toString());
counter++;
 
if (counter == 5) {
   developer.log('TIMER DONE');
    timer.cancel();
}

});

developer.log('This comes afterwards');
```

Expected out put:

```
Actual counter 0
Actual counter 1
Actual counter 2
Actual counter 3
Actual counter 4
TIMER DONE
This comes afterwards
```

The Output:

```
Actual counter 0
Actual counter 1
Actual counter 2
Actual counter 3
Actual counter 4
TIMER DONE
```

normally I should see a message 'this is afterwards' in the console, but it seems that with the cancel the complete method will be canceled.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include full sample widget how you are using this snippet

Comment: No not really, because this is everything I want to know. If you put the timer into a method and cancel it after the condition is done, it seems the timer cancel stops everything afterwards.

Comment: you like to when the timer is canceled ?

Comment: Like in my example. AFTER I canceled the timer (which was successful), I want to execute another code in the same method. This is not working. Like in my example I don't receive the log 'this comes afterwards'.

Comment: added complete workflow on update

Comment: Ok, many thanks first. It seems I have to exclude the timer from the method. I will update you.

Comment: `developer.log('This comes afterwards')` is not part of the `Timer` callback.  It will be executed immediately after *creating* the `Timer`.  There is nothing that will make it wait for the `Timer` to finish executing.  If need to asynchronously wait for a `Timer`, you can use a `Completer`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: perform operation end of timer.

You need to add logic inside if condition to perform operation.

```dart
if (counter == firmwareList.length) {
    timer.cancel();
    developer.log('This comes afterwards'); //here
      }
});
```

Here is an widget example

```dart
class TimerF extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerF({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimerF> createState() => _TimerFState();
}

class _TimerFState extends State<TimerF> {
  var counter = 0;

  Timer? timer;

  bool isTimerActive = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      print('Still timer');

      if (counter == 5) {
        timer.cancel();
        isTimerActive = false;
      }
      counter++;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("current value ${counter}"),
          if (timer?.isActive == false) Text("Timer isnt active"),
          if (isTimerActive == false) Text("Timer isnt active $isTimerActive"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

I can't see any increment on `counter` on current snippet. that's why `counter` remains 0 and doesnt meet the condition to cancel the timer.

Perhaps it will be

```dart
var counter = 0;
Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {
  print('Still timer');

  if (counter == 5) {
    timer.cancel();
  }
  counter++; //increment the value
  print('this is afterwards');
});
```

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I changed the code.

Comment: Can you include full sample widget, find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working example using a `Timer`

```
Timer? timer;

startTimer() {
  var counter = 0;
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {
    counter += 1;
    print('Actual step $counter');
    if(counter==5) {
      cancelTimer();
    }
  });
}

cancelTimer() {
  timer?.cancel();
  print('this is afterwards');
  //do something here
}
```

When you `startTimer()`, here is the output

```
Actual step 1
Actual step 2
Actual step 3
Actual step 4
Actual step 5
this is afterwards
```

Comment: OK, can you please give me an example what happens if you want to execute something else after timer?.cancel()?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can add instructions just after canceling the timer. Regardless if I print before or after canceling the timer, the output is still the same.

Comment: Many Thanks, but it's not 100% solving my problem. As you can see I changed my code again (above) to visualize the problem I faced. I want to cancel the timer and afterwards (after the timer) I want to execute some code. I may have a logic problem here. I think I have to exclude the code here.